# Putting high symmetry points labels to a band structure plot

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, electronic-band-theory, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

[image]

So far I've got this plot using Quantum Espresso. I want to put gamma, X, L, etc labels to the k-path.

Quantum Espresso's ouput states the following:

```
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x coordinate   0.0000
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.5136 0.0000   x coordinate   0.5136
 high-symmetry point: -0.5136 0.5136 0.0000   x coordinate   1.0272
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x coordinate   1.7536
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.0000 0.1556   x coordinate   1.9092
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.5136 0.1556   x coordinate   2.4228
 high-symmetry point: -0.5136 0.5136 0.1556   x coordinate   2.9365
 high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.0000 0.1556   x coordinate   3.6628
```

However I was expecting these points to be the high-symmetry points:
[image]

How should I label the k-path then?
I'd like something like this:

[image]

Is there a map between the points in the .gnu file (generated by bands.x) and the 3D K-points coordinates?
And what are the high-symmetry points quantum-espresso is telling me about? Since they don't seem to be Gamma, L, W, or X (judging by the coordinates given).
Here is the k-path:

```
 K_POINTS crystal
         300
       -0.5000000000   -0.2500000000   -0.7500000000    1.0
       -0.4937500000   -0.2468750000   -0.7406250000    1.0
       -0.4875000000   -0.2437500000   -0.7312500000    1.0
       -0.4812500000   -0.2406250000   -0.7218750000    1.0
       -0.4750000000   -0.2375000000   -0.7125000000    1.0
       -0.4687500000   -0.2343750000   -0.7031250000    1.0
       -0.4625000000   -0.2312500000   -0.6937500000    1.0
       -0.4562500000   -0.2281250000   -0.6843750000    1.0
       -0.4500000000   -0.2250000000   -0.6750000000    1.0
       -0.4437500000   -0.2218750000   -0.6656250000    1.0
       -0.4375000000   -0.2187500000   -0.6562500000    1.0
       -0.4312500000   -0.2156250000   -0.6468750000    1.0
       -0.4250000000   -0.2125000000   -0.6375000000    1.0
       -0.4187500000   -0.2093750000   -0.6281250000    1.0
       -0.4125000000   -0.2062500000   -0.6187500000    1.0
       -0.4062500000   -0.2031250000   -0.6093750000    1.0
       -0.4000000000   -0.2000000000   -0.6000000000    1.0
       -0.3937500000   -0.1968750000   -0.5906250000    1.0
       -0.3875000000   -0.1937500000   -0.5812500000    1.0
       -0.3812500000   -0.1906250000   -0.5718750000    1.0
       -0.3750000000   -0.1875000000   -0.5625000000    1.0
       -0.3687500000   -0.1843750000   -0.5531250000    1.0
       -0.3625000000   -0.1812500000   -0.5437500000    1.0
       -0.3562500000   -0.1781250000   -0.5343750000    1.0
       -0.3500000000   -0.1750000000   -0.5250000000    1.0
       -0.3437500000   -0.1718750000   -0.5156250000    1.0
       -0.3375000000   -0.1687500000   -0.5062500000    1.0
       -0.3312500000   -0.1656250000   -0.4968750000    1.0
       -0.3250000000   -0.1625000000   -0.4875000000    1.0
       -0.3187500000   -0.1593750000   -0.4781250000    1.0
       -0.3125000000   -0.1562500000   -0.4687500000    1.0
       -0.3062500000   -0.1531250000   -0.4593750000    1.0
       -0.3000000000   -0.1500000000   -0.4500000000    1.0
       -0.2937500000   -0.1468750000   -0.4406250000    1.0
       -0.2875000000   -0.1437500000   -0.4312500000    1.0
       -0.2812500000   -0.1406250000   -0.4218750000    1.0
       -0.2750000000   -0.1375000000   -0.4125000000    1.0
       -0.2687500000   -0.1343750000   -0.4031250000    1.0
       -0.2625000000   -0.1312500000   -0.3937500000    1.0
       -0.2562500000   -0.1281250000   -0.3843750000    1.0
       -0.2500000000   -0.1250000000   -0.3750000000    1.0
       -0.2437500000   -0.1218750000   -0.3656250000    1.0
       -0.2375000000   -0.1187500000   -0.3562500000    1.0
       -0.2312500000   -0.1156250000   -0.3468750000    1.0
       -0.2250000000   -0.1125000000   -0.3375000000    1.0
       -0.2187500000   -0.1093750000   -0.3281250000    1.0
       -0.2125000000   -0.1062500000   -0.3187500000    1.0
       -0.2062500000   -0.1031250000   -0.3093750000    1.0
       -0.2000000000   -0.1000000000   -0.3000000000    1.0
       -0.1937500000   -0.0968750000   -0.2906250000    1.0
       -0.1875000000   -0.0937500000   -0.2812500000    1.0
       -0.1812500000   -0.0906250000   -0.2718750000    1.0
       -0.1750000000   -0.0875000000   -0.2625000000    1.0
       -0.1687500000   -0.0843750000   -0.2531250000    1.0
       -0.1625000000   -0.0812500000   -0.2437500000    1.0
       -0.1562500000   -0.0781250000   -0.2343750000    1.0
       -0.1500000000   -0.0750000000   -0.2250000000    1.0
       -0.1437500000   -0.0718750000   -0.2156250000    1.0
       -0.1375000000   -0.0687500000   -0.2062500000    1.0
       -0.1312500000   -0.0656250000   -0.1968750000    1.0
       -0.1250000000   -0.0625000000   -0.1875000000    1.0
       -0.1187500000   -0.0593750000   -0.1781250000    1.0
       -0.1125000000   -0.0562500000   -0.1687500000    1.0
       -0.1062500000   -0.0531250000   -0.1593750000    1.0
       -0.1000000000   -0.0500000000   -0.1500000000    1.0
       -0.0937500000   -0.0468750000   -0.1406250000    1.0
       -0.0875000000   -0.0437500000   -0.1312500000    1.0
       -0.0812500000   -0.0406250000   -0.1218750000    1.0
       -0.0750000000   -0.0375000000   -0.1125000000    1.0
       -0.0687500000   -0.0343750000   -0.1031250000    1.0
       -0.0625000000   -0.0312500000   -0.0937500000    1.0
       -0.0562500000   -0.0281250000   -0.0843750000    1.0
       -0.0500000000   -0.0250000000   -0.0750000000    1.0
       -0.0437500000   -0.0218750000   -0.0656250000    1.0
       -0.0375000000   -0.0187500000   -0.0562500000    1.0
       -0.0312500000   -0.0156250000   -0.0468750000    1.0
       -0.0250000000   -0.0125000000   -0.0375000000    1.0
       -0.0187500000   -0.0093750000   -0.0281250000    1.0
       -0.0125000000   -0.0062500000   -0.0187500000    1.0
       -0.0062500000   -0.0031250000   -0.0093750000    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    1.0
       -0.0070422535    0.0000000000   -0.0070422535    1.0
       -0.0140845070    0.0000000000   -0.0140845070    1.0
       -0.0211267606    0.0000000000   -0.0211267606    1.0
       -0.0281690141    0.0000000000   -0.0281690141    1.0
       -0.0352112676    0.0000000000   -0.0352112676    1.0
       -0.0422535211    0.0000000000   -0.0422535211    1.0
       -0.0492957746    0.0000000000   -0.0492957746    1.0
       -0.0563380282    0.0000000000   -0.0563380282    1.0
       -0.0633802817    0.0000000000   -0.0633802817    1.0
       -0.0704225352    0.0000000000   -0.0704225352    1.0
       -0.0774647887    0.0000000000   -0.0774647887    1.0
       -0.0845070423    0.0000000000   -0.0845070423    1.0
       -0.0915492958    0.0000000000   -0.0915492958    1.0
       -0.0985915493    0.0000000000   -0.0985915493    1.0
       -0.1056338028    0.0000000000   -0.1056338028    1.0
       -0.1126760563    0.0000000000   -0.1126760563    1.0
       -0.1197183099    0.0000000000   -0.1197183099    1.0
       -0.1267605634    0.0000000000   -0.1267605634    1.0
       -0.1338028169    0.0000000000   -0.1338028169    1.0
       -0.1408450704    0.0000000000   -0.1408450704    1.0
       -0.1478873239    0.0000000000   -0.1478873239    1.0
       -0.1549295775    0.0000000000   -0.1549295775    1.0
       -0.1619718310    0.0000000000   -0.1619718310    1.0
       -0.1690140845    0.0000000000   -0.1690140845    1.0
       -0.1760563380    0.0000000000   -0.1760563380    1.0
       -0.1830985915    0.0000000000   -0.1830985915    1.0
       -0.1901408451    0.0000000000   -0.1901408451    1.0
       -0.1971830986    0.0000000000   -0.1971830986    1.0
       -0.2042253521    0.0000000000   -0.2042253521    1.0
       -0.2112676056    0.0000000000   -0.2112676056    1.0
       -0.2183098592    0.0000000000   -0.2183098592    1.0
       -0.2253521127    0.0000000000   -0.2253521127    1.0
       -0.2323943662    0.0000000000   -0.2323943662    1.0
       -0.2394366197    0.0000000000   -0.2394366197    1.0
       -0.2464788732    0.0000000000   -0.2464788732    1.0
       -0.2535211268    0.0000000000   -0.2535211268    1.0
       -0.2605633803    0.0000000000   -0.2605633803    1.0
       -0.2676056338    0.0000000000   -0.2676056338    1.0
       -0.2746478873    0.0000000000   -0.2746478873    1.0
       -0.2816901408    0.0000000000   -0.2816901408    1.0
       -0.2887323944    0.0000000000   -0.2887323944    1.0
       -0.2957746479    0.0000000000   -0.2957746479    1.0
       -0.3028169014    0.0000000000   -0.3028169014    1.0
       -0.3098591549    0.0000000000   -0.3098591549    1.0
       -0.3169014085    0.0000000000   -0.3169014085    1.0
       -0.3239436620    0.0000000000   -0.3239436620    1.0
       -0.3309859155    0.0000000000   -0.3309859155    1.0
       -0.3380281690    0.0000000000   -0.3380281690    1.0
       -0.3450704225    0.0000000000   -0.3450704225    1.0
       -0.3521126761    0.0000000000   -0.3521126761    1.0
       -0.3591549296    0.0000000000   -0.3591549296    1.0
       -0.3661971831    0.0000000000   -0.3661971831    1.0
       -0.3732394366    0.0000000000   -0.3732394366    1.0
       -0.3802816901    0.0000000000   -0.3802816901    1.0
       -0.3873239437    0.0000000000   -0.3873239437    1.0
       -0.3943661972    0.0000000000   -0.3943661972    1.0
       -0.4014084507    0.0000000000   -0.4014084507    1.0
       -0.4084507042    0.0000000000   -0.4084507042    1.0
       -0.4154929577    0.0000000000   -0.4154929577    1.0
       -0.4225352113    0.0000000000   -0.4225352113    1.0
       -0.4295774648    0.0000000000   -0.4295774648    1.0
       -0.4366197183    0.0000000000   -0.4366197183    1.0
       -0.4436619718    0.0000000000   -0.4436619718    1.0
       -0.4507042254    0.0000000000   -0.4507042254    1.0
       -0.4577464789    0.0000000000   -0.4577464789    1.0
       -0.4647887324    0.0000000000   -0.4647887324    1.0
       -0.4718309859    0.0000000000   -0.4718309859    1.0
       -0.4788732394    0.0000000000   -0.4788732394    1.0
       -0.4859154930    0.0000000000   -0.4859154930    1.0
       -0.4929577465    0.0000000000   -0.4929577465    1.0
       -0.5000000000    0.0000000000   -0.5000000000    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0069444444   -0.5069444444    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0138888889   -0.5138888889    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0208333333   -0.5208333333    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0277777778   -0.5277777778    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0347222222   -0.5347222222    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0416666667   -0.5416666667    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0486111111   -0.5486111111    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0555555556   -0.5555555556    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0625000000   -0.5625000000    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0694444444   -0.5694444444    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0763888889   -0.5763888889    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0833333333   -0.5833333333    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0902777778   -0.5902777778    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.0972222222   -0.5972222222    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1041666667   -0.6041666667    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1111111111   -0.6111111111    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1180555556   -0.6180555556    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1250000000   -0.6250000000    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1319444444   -0.6319444444    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1388888889   -0.6388888889    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1458333333   -0.6458333333    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1527777778   -0.6527777778    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1597222222   -0.6597222222    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1666666667   -0.6666666667    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1736111111   -0.6736111111    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1805555556   -0.6805555556    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1875000000   -0.6875000000    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.1944444444   -0.6944444444    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2013888889   -0.7013888889    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2083333333   -0.7083333333    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2152777778   -0.7152777778    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2222222222   -0.7222222222    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2291666667   -0.7291666667    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2361111111   -0.7361111111    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2430555556   -0.7430555556    1.0
       -0.5000000000   -0.2500000000   -0.7500000000    1.0
       -0.4900000000   -0.2450000000   -0.7450000000    1.0
       -0.4800000000   -0.2400000000   -0.7400000000    1.0
       -0.4700000000   -0.2350000000   -0.7350000000    1.0
       -0.4600000000   -0.2300000000   -0.7300000000    1.0
       -0.4500000000   -0.2250000000   -0.7250000000    1.0
       -0.4400000000   -0.2200000000   -0.7200000000    1.0
       -0.4300000000   -0.2150000000   -0.7150000000    1.0
       -0.4200000000   -0.2100000000   -0.7100000000    1.0
       -0.4100000000   -0.2050000000   -0.7050000000    1.0
       -0.4000000000   -0.2000000000   -0.7000000000    1.0
       -0.3900000000   -0.1950000000   -0.6950000000    1.0
       -0.3800000000   -0.1900000000   -0.6900000000    1.0
       -0.3700000000   -0.1850000000   -0.6850000000    1.0
       -0.3600000000   -0.1800000000   -0.6800000000    1.0
       -0.3500000000   -0.1750000000   -0.6750000000    1.0
       -0.3400000000   -0.1700000000   -0.6700000000    1.0
       -0.3300000000   -0.1650000000   -0.6650000000    1.0
       -0.3200000000   -0.1600000000   -0.6600000000    1.0
       -0.3100000000   -0.1550000000   -0.6550000000    1.0
       -0.3000000000   -0.1500000000   -0.6500000000    1.0
       -0.2900000000   -0.1450000000   -0.6450000000    1.0
       -0.2800000000   -0.1400000000   -0.6400000000    1.0
       -0.2700000000   -0.1350000000   -0.6350000000    1.0
       -0.2600000000   -0.1300000000   -0.6300000000    1.0
       -0.2500000000   -0.1250000000   -0.6250000000    1.0
       -0.2400000000   -0.1200000000   -0.6200000000    1.0
       -0.2300000000   -0.1150000000   -0.6150000000    1.0
       -0.2200000000   -0.1100000000   -0.6100000000    1.0
       -0.2100000000   -0.1050000000   -0.6050000000    1.0
       -0.2000000000   -0.1000000000   -0.6000000000    1.0
       -0.1900000000   -0.0950000000   -0.5950000000    1.0
       -0.1800000000   -0.0900000000   -0.5900000000    1.0
       -0.1700000000   -0.0850000000   -0.5850000000    1.0
       -0.1600000000   -0.0800000000   -0.5800000000    1.0
       -0.1500000000   -0.0750000000   -0.5750000000    1.0
       -0.1400000000   -0.0700000000   -0.5700000000    1.0
       -0.1300000000   -0.0650000000   -0.5650000000    1.0
       -0.1200000000   -0.0600000000   -0.5600000000    1.0
       -0.1100000000   -0.0550000000   -0.5550000000    1.0
       -0.1000000000   -0.0500000000   -0.5500000000    1.0
       -0.0900000000   -0.0450000000   -0.5450000000    1.0
       -0.0800000000   -0.0400000000   -0.5400000000    1.0
       -0.0700000000   -0.0350000000   -0.5350000000    1.0
       -0.0600000000   -0.0300000000   -0.5300000000    1.0
       -0.0500000000   -0.0250000000   -0.5250000000    1.0
       -0.0400000000   -0.0200000000   -0.5200000000    1.0
       -0.0300000000   -0.0150000000   -0.5150000000    1.0
       -0.0200000000   -0.0100000000   -0.5100000000    1.0
       -0.0100000000   -0.0050000000   -0.5050000000    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.5000000000    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4919354839    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4838709677    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4758064516    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4677419355    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4596774194    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4516129032    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4435483871    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4354838710    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4274193548    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4193548387    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4112903226    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.4032258065    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3951612903    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3870967742    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3790322581    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3709677419    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3629032258    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3548387097    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3467741935    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3387096774    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3306451613    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3225806452    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3145161290    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.3064516129    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2983870968    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2903225806    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2822580645    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2741935484    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2661290323    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2580645161    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2500000000    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2419354839    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2338709677    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2258064516    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2177419355    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2096774194    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.2016129032    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1935483871    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1854838710    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1774193548    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1693548387    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1612903226    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1532258065    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1451612903    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1370967742    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1290322581    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1209677419    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1129032258    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.1048387097    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0967741935    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0887096774    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0806451613    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0725806452    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0645161290    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0564516129    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0483870968    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0403225806    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0322580645    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0241935484    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0161290323    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000   -0.0080645161    1.0
        0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    1.0
```

And here 1 band out of 8 from the .gnu file.

```
0.0000   -1.4027
0.0140   -1.4620
0.0280   -1.5237
0.0420   -1.5880
0.0560   -1.6550
0.0699   -1.7241
0.0839   -1.7950
0.0979   -1.8679
0.1119   -1.9426
0.1259   -2.0196
0.1399   -2.0974
0.1539   -2.1765
0.1679   -2.2567
0.1819   -2.3381
0.1958   -2.4201
0.2098   -2.5027
0.2238   -2.5864
0.2378   -2.6698
0.2518   -2.7536
0.2658   -2.8373
0.2798   -2.9210
0.2938   -3.0046
0.3077   -3.0878
0.3217   -3.1708
0.3357   -3.2532
0.3497   -3.3353
0.3637   -3.4166
0.3777   -3.4971
0.3917   -3.5766
0.4057   -3.6555
0.4197   -3.7332
0.4336   -3.8102
0.4476   -3.8861
0.4616   -3.9610
0.4756   -4.0348
0.4896   -4.1073
0.5036   -4.1787
0.5176   -4.2488
0.5316   -4.3177
0.5456   -4.3850
0.5595   -4.4512
0.5735   -4.5160
0.5875   -4.5794
0.6015   -4.6414
0.6155   -4.7018
0.6295   -4.7607
0.6435   -4.8183
0.6575   -4.8744
0.6714   -4.9290
0.6854   -4.9820
0.6994   -5.0334
0.7134   -5.0837
0.7274   -5.1315
0.7414   -5.1782
0.7554   -5.2233
0.7694   -5.2668
0.7834   -5.3087
0.7973   -5.3492
0.8113   -5.3878
0.8253   -5.4247
0.8393   -5.4599
0.8533   -5.4931
0.8673   -5.5250
0.8813   -5.5552
0.8953   -5.5837
0.9093   -5.6105
0.9232   -5.6356
0.9372   -5.6593
0.9512   -5.6809
0.9652   -5.7010
0.9792   -5.7193
0.9932   -5.7360
1.0072   -5.7511
1.0212   -5.7641
1.0352   -5.7754
1.0491   -5.7850
1.0631   -5.7928
1.0771   -5.7989
1.0911   -5.8033
1.1051   -5.8059
1.1191   -5.8068
1.1332   -5.8059
1.1473   -5.8032
1.1614   -5.7988
1.1755   -5.7926
1.1896   -5.7847
1.2037   -5.7749
1.2178   -5.7634
1.2319   -5.7502
1.2460   -5.7348
1.2601   -5.7180
1.2742   -5.6995
1.2883   -5.6786
1.3024   -5.6565
1.3165   -5.6328
1.3305   -5.6072
1.3446   -5.5799
1.3587   -5.5509
1.3728   -5.5201
1.3869   -5.4876
1.4010   -5.4533
1.4151   -5.4181
1.4292   -5.3804
1.4433   -5.3410
1.4574   -5.2998
1.4715   -5.2569
1.4856   -5.2124
1.4997   -5.1661
1.5138   -5.1181
1.5279   -5.0685
1.5420   -5.0171
1.5561   -4.9641
1.5702   -4.9102
1.5843   -4.8538
1.5984   -4.7960
1.6125   -4.7363
1.6266   -4.6750
1.6407   -4.6121
1.6548   -4.5475
1.6689   -4.4804
1.6830   -4.4127
1.6971   -4.3433
1.7112   -4.2723
1.7253   -4.1997
1.7394   -4.1243
1.7535   -4.0487
1.7676   -3.9714
1.7817   -3.8927
1.7958   -3.8124
1.8099   -3.7311
1.8240   -3.6478
1.8381   -3.5631
1.8522   -3.4769
1.8663   -3.3892
1.8804   -3.3001
1.8945   -3.2096
1.9086   -3.1175
1.9227   -3.0242
1.9368   -2.9295
1.9508   -2.8335
1.9649   -2.7361
1.9790   -2.6375
1.9931   -2.5375
2.0072   -2.4358
2.0213   -2.3333
2.0354   -2.2296
2.0495   -2.1247
2.0636   -2.0187
2.0777   -1.9115
2.0918   -1.8031
2.1059   -1.6927
2.1200   -1.5823
2.1339   -1.5819
2.1478   -1.5810
2.1617   -1.5798
2.1756   -1.5779
2.1895   -1.5752
2.2034   -1.5719
2.2173   -1.5680
2.2312   -1.5641
2.2451   -1.5592
2.2590   -1.5538
2.2729   -1.5486
2.2868   -1.5424
2.3007   -1.5358
2.3146   -1.5286
2.3285   -1.5214
2.3425   -1.5139
2.3564   -1.5063
2.3703   -1.4988
2.3842   -1.4904
2.3981   -1.4826
2.4120   -1.4748
2.4259   -1.4668
2.4398   -1.4593
2.4537   -1.4520
2.4676   -1.4450
2.4815   -1.4384
2.4954   -1.4322
2.5093   -1.4265
2.5232   -1.4213
2.5371   -1.4161
2.5510   -1.4121
2.5649   -1.4088
2.5788   -1.4061
2.5927   -1.4043
2.6066   -1.4031
2.6205   -1.4027
2.6346   -1.4686
2.6488   -1.5348
2.6630   -1.6011
2.6771   -1.6685
2.6913   -1.7346
2.7054   -1.8004
2.7196   -1.8660
2.7337   -1.9306
2.7479   -1.9946
2.7620   -2.0576
2.7762   -2.1198
2.7904   -2.1811
2.8045   -2.2412
2.8187   -2.3003
2.8328   -2.3582
2.8470   -2.4148
2.8611   -2.4701
2.8753   -2.5241
2.8894   -2.5767
2.9036   -2.6285
2.9178   -2.6783
2.9319   -2.7265
2.9461   -2.7733
2.9602   -2.8178
2.9744   -2.8615
2.9885   -2.9036
3.0027   -2.9444
3.0168   -2.9834
3.0310   -3.0202
3.0452   -3.0558
3.0593   -3.0897
3.0735   -3.1220
3.0876   -3.1526
3.1018   -3.1815
3.1159   -3.2088
3.1301   -3.2342
3.1442   -3.2580
3.1584   -3.2800
3.1726   -3.3003
3.1867   -3.3188
3.2009   -3.3357
3.2150   -3.3507
3.2292   -3.3640
3.2433   -3.3755
3.2575   -3.3852
3.2716   -3.3932
3.2858   -3.3994
3.2999   -3.4038
3.3141   -3.4057
3.3283   -3.4059
3.3422   -3.4099
3.3562   -3.4223
3.3702   -3.4417
3.3842   -3.4693
3.3982   -3.5022
3.4121   -3.5409
3.4261   -3.5847
3.4401   -3.6329
3.4541   -3.6847
3.4681   -3.7396
3.4821   -3.7973
3.4960   -3.8567
3.5100   -3.9176
3.5240   -3.9796
3.5380   -4.0424
3.5520   -4.1055
3.5659   -4.1690
3.5799   -4.2324
3.5939   -4.2956
3.6079   -4.3584
3.6219   -4.4207
3.6358   -4.4823
3.6498   -4.5431
3.6638   -4.6031
3.6778   -4.6618
3.6918   -4.7197
3.7058   -4.7764
3.7197   -4.8320
3.7337   -4.8863
3.7477   -4.9393
3.7617   -4.9908
3.7757   -5.0411
3.7896   -5.0899
3.8036   -5.1373
3.8176   -5.1827
3.8316   -5.2271
3.8456   -5.2700
3.8595   -5.3113
3.8735   -5.3512
3.8875   -5.3894
3.9015   -5.4260
3.9155   -5.4609
3.9295   -5.4945
3.9434   -5.5262
3.9574   -5.5557
3.9714   -5.5840
3.9854   -5.6107
3.9994   -5.6357
4.0133   -5.6595
4.0273   -5.6811
4.0413   -5.7010
4.0553   -5.7197
4.0693   -5.7362
4.0832   -5.7512
4.0972   -5.7642
4.1112   -5.7755
4.1252   -5.7850
4.1392   -5.7928
4.1532   -5.7989
4.1671   -5.8033
4.1811   -5.8059
4.1951   -5.8068
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have no idea how to answer this question.

Comment: I've just updated it with more details. I believe the 2 main questions are now clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about diagnosing and parsing the output of a particular software.

Comment: is there a particular branch of stack exchange that answers questions related to softwares like Quantum Espresso and the likes? if not, is there an online forum similar to stack exchange for things related to this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quantum Espresso generates bands data in the format recognized by GNU plot with the extension .gnu. It calculates the distance between corresponding points and generates the .gnu file as mentioned above.
So if you gave your input k points in the crystal_b format, the first value in the .gnu file will correspond to the first high symmetry point in the input. So depending on the number of points in a given symmetry direction, you can count and mark your points.

Eg (if your input in crystal_b format)
K_POINTS {crystal_b}
2
0.00 0.00 0.00 40 | G
1.00 0.00 1.00 40 | X

So in the output(.gnu) file the first value will be the Gamma point and the 41st value will be X point since there are 40 values in between Gamma-->X.

Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I got it :) But I've got one question left. What is the ouput of quantum espresso, the one that says  high-symmetry point:  0.0000 0.5136 0.0000   x coordinate   0.5136 etc for? I mean, I didn't even choose 8 points when selecting the K-path in xcrysden. My path was: W-Gamma-X-W-L-Gamma, with a total of 300 points.